# LINQ query is null

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I am building a WinForms application that searches for books in the Database.

I have four tables: 
Author,Book,Country,Genre;

There is a field in "Book" table called "Year". 
I added **startDate** and **endDate** fields, so it can search for specific book released between the given two years(startDate and endDate both are integers). That is where my troubles began.

This is how I parse inputs.

```
int startDateResult = 0;
int? startDate = null;

if (inputStartDate == string.Empty)
{
    startDate = null;
}
else
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(inputStartDate, out startDateResult))
    {
        startDate = startDateResult;
    }
    else throw new Exception("Please input correct year");
}

int endDateResult = 0;
int? endDate = null;

if (inputEndDate == string.Empty)
{
    endDate = null;
}
else
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(inputEndDate, out endDateResult))
    {
        endDate = endDateResult;
    }
    else throw new Exception("Please input correct year");
}
```

This is the LINQ query I am using for searching.

```
specificBookForAuthor = _context.Books.Where(c =>            
    (c.Author.Name.Contains(First) || c.Author.Surname.Contains(Last))

    && book==string.Empty?true: c.Name.Contains(book)

    && country == string.Empty ? true : c.Author.Country.Name.Contains(country)

    && genre == string.Empty ? true : c.Genre.Name.Contains(genre)

    && inputYear == string.Empty ? true : c.Year==year

    && inputStartDate == string.Empty ? true : c.Year >= startDate

    && inputEndDate == string.Empty ? true : c.Year <= endDate

).Select(b => b).ToList();
```

This query did not work. Then, I tried to comment all the lines except "inputEndDate", typed 0 in startDate and 5000 in endDate. After Debug, found out, that "specificBookAuthor"-s count was 1. Which was CORRECT.

Commented Code :

```
specificBookForAuthor = _context.Books.Where(c =>

    (c.Author.Name.Contains(First) || c.Author.Surname.Contains(Last))

    //&& book==string.Empty?true: c.Name.Contains(book)

    //&& country == string.Empty ? true : 
    //    c.Author.Country.Name.Contains(country)

    // && genre == string.Empty ? true : c.Genre.Name.Contains(genre)

    // && inputYear == string.Empty ? true : c.Year==year

    // && inputStartDate == string.Empty ? true : c.Year >= startDate

    inputEndDate == string.Empty ? true : c.Year <= endDate

).Select(b => b).ToList();
```

Did the same with inputStartDate(commented inputEndDate line and uncommented inputStartDate). Worked fine.

I get the problem when I leave both of the fields uncommented. Like this:

```
specificBookForAuthor = _context.Books.Where(c =>

    (c.Author.Name.Contains(First) || c.Author.Surname.Contains(Last))

    //&& book==string.Empty?true: c.Name.Contains(book)

    //&& country == string.Empty ? true :c.Author.Country.Name.Contains(country)


    // && genre == string.Empty ? true : c.Genre.Name.Contains(genre)

    // && inputYear == string.Empty ? true : c.Year==year

    && inputStartDate == string.Empty ? true : c.Year >= startDate

    && inputEndDate == string.Empty ? true : c.Year <= endDate

).Select(b => b).ToList();
```

In that case, "specificBookAuthor"-s count is NULL instead of 1.

Comment: You need to debug this. Cut the problem in half, test the UI by entering your data and seeing what you get (using `Debug.WriteLine` or `MessageBox.Show`). Then debug the query by fixing your inputs and doing what you started doing (commenting out parts) and figuring what is failing as you add in the commented out code a bit at a time.

Comment: you can use EF Profiler or Sql Profiler (if use sql server) and see generated query to find the problem quickly

Comment: @Flydog57 I did debug it. Returns correct data when I leave only one field(either inputStartDate or inputEndDate) it works fine. Couldn't see why is null returned

Comment: What type of LINQ are we talking about? Also, why don't you test if `startDate` and `endDate` are null instead of the input strings? In other words, the first part of your question could be removed, it's not relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Could you test the following change which may not be directly related to the issue, but it can give you a more readable/debugable code?

Rewrite your code to this:

```
specificBookForAuthor = _context.Books.Where(c => 
    (c.Author.Name.Contains(First) || c.Author.Surname.Contains(Last)));

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(book))
    specificBookForAuthor = specificBookForAuthor.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(book));

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(country))
    specificBookForAuthor = specificBookForAuthor.Where(c => c.Author.Country.Name.Contains(country));

//....and so on with your other conditions;
//....finally:

specificBookForAuthor = specificBookForAuthor.ToList();
```

As I said, this may not resolve your problem, but this way you can properly debug condition by condition and maybe then you can find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So every `Book` has a property `Year`, representing the year in which a book was published.

Furthermore you have two nullable integers `startDate` and `endDate` and you want to limit the selected books to books published between `startDate` and `endDate`, with special cases if one or both of these values are null.

You have an input `IQueryable<Book>` and as output you want the query that will only fetch the books between `startDate` and `endDate`, with special treatment if these values are null.

To keep it readable, testable and maintainable, I suggest an extension function. See [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static IQueryable<Book> WherePublishedBetween(this IQueryable<Book> books,
    Year? start,
    Year? end)
{
    if (start.HasValue)
    {
        if (end.HasValue)
            return books.Where(book => start.Value <= book.Year && book.Year <= end.Value);
        else
            return books.Where(book => start.Value <= book.Year);
    }
    else
    {   // no start value
        if (end.HasValue)
            return books.Where(book => book.Year <= end.Value);
        else
            return books;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
int? startYear = ...
int? endYear = ...
var queryBooks = myDbContext.Books
    .Where(book => book.Author.Name.Contains(First)
                || book.Author.Surname.Contains(Last)
           && ... // check other properties)
    .WherePublishedBetween(startYear, endYear)

    // continue with the query, with whatever LINQ you need
    .Select(book => ...)
```

The LINQ expression builder will be smart enough to combine these two `Where` statements using [Expression.AndAlso](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.andalso?view=netframework-4.7.2)